# Is unix join strictly lexical?

Tags: unix

I have to process many ('00s) two-column delimited files that are numerically sorted by their first column (a long int that can range from 857 to 293823421 for example).

The processing is simple enough: iterate through a loop to left-join the files using one of them as 'anchor' (the 'left' file in the join), using `join`'s `-e` and `-o` options to fill in the NULLs.

Question: is there any way `join` (from Core Utils 8.13) can process these joins as-is, or must I add a `sort -k1,1` step to ensure lexical order prior to each join ?

Everything I've read searching this tells me I have to, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some clever trick to avoid the extra sorting. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, `join` does not support numeric comparisons. However, from your description, it sounds like you can convert your first field into an already-string-sorted form by zero-padding it, and then convert it back by de-zero-padding it. For example, here is a function that performs a `join -e NULL` on two files that match your description (as I understand it):

```
function join_by_numeric_first_field () {
    local file1="$1"
    local file2="$2"
    join -e NULL <(awk '{printf("%020d\t%s\n", $1, $2)}' "$file1") \
                 <(awk '{printf("%020d\t%s\n", $1, $2)}' "$file2") \
    | awk '{printf("%d\t%s\n", $1, $2)}'
}
```

(The `awk '{printf("%020d\t%s\n", $1, $2)}'` reads each line of a two-column input and re-prints out the two columns, separated by a tab, but treating the first column as a decimal integer and zero-padding it out to twenty characters. The `awk '{printf("%d\t%s\n", $1, $2)}'` does the same thing, except that it *doesn't* zero-pad the decimal integer, so it has the effect of stripping out any zero-padding that was there.)

Whether this is a better approach than `sort`-ing will depend on the size of your files, and on how flexible you need to be in supporting files that don't quite match your description. This approach scales linearly with the file-size, but is significantly more complicated, and is also a bit more fragile, in that the `awk` commands expect a pretty specific input-format. The `sort` approach is much simpler, but will not perform as well for large files.

Comment: +1 but please note that `<(cmd)` is a Bashism, and won't work in other shells. If (as your tagging suggests) true Unix portability is a concern, you could pull this off with temporary files ... but then simply sorting your input lexically may be the path of least resistance and/or pain.

Comment: Thank you for the idea and the code. I'll time both approaches (the files are fairly large, definitely worth running the comparison).